# Is the homology long exact sequence natural?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

For instance, the Tor (or any other derived functor of an additive functor) long exact sequence associated to a short exact sequence of modules. The naturality is stated in many books as "for any commutative diagram of short exact sequences the induced diagram of long exact sequences is commutative".

I see clearly that "for any commutative diagram of short exact sequences *there exists an* induced diagram of long exact sequences which is commutative". But I do not understand why the above stronger formulation is also valid.

For instance, I can compute the connecting homomorphism of the long exact sequence constructing a short exact sequence of complexes (using e.g. the horseshoe lemma). But if I multiply all the maps in the three complexes by -1, we can againg compute the connecting homomorphisms, and the result is that the new connecting homomorphism is -1 times the older one. So the connecting homomorphism is not unique. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$Firstly, naturality of the long exact sequence and uniqueness of the long exact sequence are two different things. That the long exact sequence is natural is a fairly simple consequence of the construction and the naturality of the long exact sequence in homology for an exact sequence of nonnegative complexes $0\to X_\bullet\to Y_\bullet\to Z_\bullet\to0$, which itself is a reasonably straightforward exercise to verify. Your question has two conflicting subquestions but if you want me to elaborate on that more I can.

The connecting homomorphism is not unique. It is not even unique if you stipulate that it is natural. But, who cares? There is a canonical choice of construction of the connecting homomorphism from the Snake Lemma, which makes homology a $\delta$-functor. Appropriately stated, any other choice of natural connecting homomorphism so that $H_\bullet$ would be a $\delta$-functor would give you something naturally isomorphic with the canonical one. So there is no loss in focusing on the canonical one. And there is something to be gained, because then you can unambiguously establish sign conventions and rules of manipulation of homology classes etc.

Similarly, if $S_\bullet,T_\bullet$ are two left derived functors of $A\otimes_R-$, they would have two notions of connecting homomorphism. However they would be isomorphic, so there is again no loss. That is to say, if $0\to X\to Y\to Z\to0$ were a short exact sequence of left $R$-modules then the connectors $\delta^S:S_k(Z)\to S_{k+1}(X),\delta^T:T_k(Z)\to T_{k+1}(X)$ would be joined by a natural isomorphism of $\delta$-functors $\lambda:S\cong T$. $$\begin{CD}S_k(Y)@>>>S_k(Z)@>\delta^S>>S_{k+1}(X)@>>>S_{k+1}(Y)\\@V\cong V\lambda V@V\cong V\lambda V@V\cong V\lambda V@V\cong V\lambda V\\T_k(Y)@>>>T_k(Z)@>>\delta^T>T_{k+1}(X)@>>>T_{k+1}(Y)\end{CD}$$So, if you have a canonical construction $T$ with canonical choice of connector then you may as well stick with it, with no loss, since any other viable construction would be isomorphic (uniquely isomorphic, in fact).

That is, the canonical construction of $\mathsf{Tor}_R(A,-)$ via projective resolutions (even, *canonical* projective resolutions, which are available for $R\mathsf{Mod}$) and using the Snake and Horseshoe lemmae to produce the canonical connector $\partial$ ... is not unique, but is unique up to unique isomorphism and that's good enough. You could redefine $\mathsf{Tor}_R(A,-)$ to be the same on objects and morphisms but alter its connector by $(-1)$. Sure... and it works. But it's isomorphic to what you started and it's a bit weird, and there is no real difference between one choice or the other purely mathematically but from a human-friendly perspective, it's best to stick with the conventions.